# Django: how to modify form field order of bound form with one unbound field?

Tags: django, forms

I have an update form with 4 fields to display

3 of them are related to a class to which the form is bound
the last field (country) is only for information and I would like that field to be display in first position
currently, it is displayed at the end of my form...

I tryed to use field_order but country field is ignored...

form.py

```
class ParametrageForm(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ParametrageForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.request = request
        self.language = request.session.get('language')
        self.user = request.user.id # id de l'utilisateur
        self.user_pays = request.session.get('user_pays') # pays de l'utilisateur
        self.user_site_type = request.session.get('user_site_type') 
        self.user_site = request.session.get('user_site') 
        instance = Parametrage.objects.get(asp_par_cle = kwargs['instance'].asp_par_cle) 

        SITE_CONCERNE = Site.option_list_sites(self.language)
        if self.language == 'en':
            country= Site.objects.get(sit_abr = instance.asp_par_loc).reg.pay.pay_nom_eng
        elif self.language == 'fr':
            country= Site.objects.get(sit_abr = instance.asp_par_loc).reg.pay.pay_nom_fra
        else:
            country= Site.objects.get(sit_abr = instance.asp_par_loc).reg.pay.pay_nom_eng

        self.fields["country"] = forms.CharField(label = _("Country"),widget=forms.TextInput,initial=country, disabled=True)
        self.fields["asp_par_loc"] = forms.ChoiceField(label = _("Site concerned by settings"), widget=forms.Select, choices=SITE_CONCERNE,)
        self.fields["asp_par_ale"] = forms.IntegerField(label = _("Stock alert value for this site"), widget=forms.TextInput,)
        self.fields["asp_par_con"] = forms.IntegerField(label = _("Stock confort value for this site"), widget=forms.TextInput,)    

    class Meta:
        model = Parametrage
        fields = ('asp_par_loc','asp_par_ale','asp_par_con',)

    field_order = ['country','asp_par_loc','asp_par_ale','asp_par_con',]
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
    self.fields["country"] = forms.CharField(label = _("Country"),widget=forms.TextInput,initial=country, disabled=True)
```

with

```
    country = forms.CharField(label = _("Country"),widget=forms.TextInput,initial=country, disabled=True)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. It is already a field and I try what you say and have an error because filed is not recongnized (because not part of Parametrage model)

Answer (score 0):

I found how to solve my issue:

I defined 'country' field outside of the **init**
and then filed_order works

but doing that, I do not have access to my initial country value, set in **init** (country= Site.objects.get(sit_abr = instance.asp_par_loc).reg.pay.pay_nom_eng)

I must improve my Python understanding...